# How can I make the Report Viewer Control responsive

Tags: responsive-design, ssrs-2008

Want to open my report viewer containing a page in a Model popup. When I maximize the Model popup screen, all of the container div are taking width as per the screen width, but the Report viewer is not responsive.

Can any body suggest solution regarding this

Answer (score 1):

You should try this solution

*Zoom : Sets the report zoom value as an integer percentage or a string constant. Standard string values include Page Width and Whole Page. This parameter is ignored by versions of Internet Explorer earlier than Internet Explorer 5.0 and all non-Microsoft browsers. The default value of this parameter is 100.
For example in Native mode:*

```
http://myrshost/reportserver?/Sales&rc:Zoom=Page Width
```

Ref : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152835.aspx